# JQuery Plugins and JQuery noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, qtip2

I'm using **jQuery** in `noConflict` mode since my code is a JS widget running on a host page.

I would like to have my code dynamically load a jQuery plugin ([qTip2](http://qtip2.com/)) without interfering with the page's jQuery.

The problem is that the plugin binds its $ variable to the local page's jQuery.

I tried loading the plugin before calling `noConflict()` and it works, but it leaves a period where the global $ is pointing to my jQuery.

Here's the code (I've omitted the `loadJsFile` function to keep it short. It adds the script to the head and calls back when it's loaded):

```
  (function trackJq(timesToGo) {
    if (timesToGo-- > 0) {
      log("timed");
      setTimeout(function() {trackJq(timesToGo)}, 20);
    }
  })(10)

  function isDef() { return typeof $.qtip !== 'undefined'; }

  function log (msg) { console.log(msg + " $:" + jQuery.fn.jquery + " qTip:" + isDef()); }

  log("Before loading my jQuery");
  loadJsFile("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js", function() {
    log("After loading my jQuery");
    loadJsFile("http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js", function() {
      log("After loading qTip");
      $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
      log("After calling noconflict");

      // rest of code here...

    });
  });
```

and the output (shows that there's a time interval where my jQuery takes over):

```
timed                    $:1.2.3  qTip:false
Before loading my jQuery $:1.2.3  qTip:false
timed                    $:1.2.3  qTip:false
After loading my jQuery  $:1.11.0 qTip:false
timed                    $:1.11.0 qTip:false
timed                    $:1.11.0 qTip:false
timed                    $:1.11.0 qTip:false
After loading qTip       $:1.11.0 qTip:true
After calling noconflict $:1.2.3  qTip:false
timed                    $:1.2.3  qTip:false
timed                    $:1.2.3  qTip:false
timed                    $:1.2.3  qTip:false
timed                    $:1.2.3  qTip:false
timed                    $:1.2.3  qTip:false
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't do what every tutorial tells you to do, wrap your plugin in a IIFE that creates a closure scope ?

Comment: Why is your plugin... including it's own version of jquery? if the page author is using an ancient version of jquery, that's not your problem.

Comment: @adeneo, what does IIFE mean?

Comment: @adeneo, not sure what IIFE means, but wrapping my script in a closure doesn't work since qTip is loaded async. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's when you do `(function ( $ ) { plugin here })(jQuery);` I don't think I've ever seen a jQuery plugin that loads jQuery and uses noConflict, ever ?

Comment: @KevinB, I'm trying to reduce the dependencies of my script to a minimum, so if the owner of the page has some reason why he can't use jQuery or use an older version he still can use my widget.

Comment: Right, but that's not your problem! if anything, doing this with your script makes it *less* useable, i sure as hell won't include a plugin/widget on any of my pages that includes it's own library.

Comment: @adeneo, my code is not a plugin. It's a JS widget.

Comment: If you're worried about dependencies, ensure that you are using methods within your plugin that are backwards compatible such as .bind and .delegate instead of .on. At least that way you know your plugin *might* work with 1.3.2+

Comment: Good for you, it's pretty much the same thing with a few differences. Figure out what your widget needs, check for the presence of jQuery, and if it's not present, polyfill *what you need* with your code, as you shouldn't really have to include jQuery or use noConflict inside a widget, plugin, script whatever that other people can include etc.

Comment: So to be specific, your advise for me is to implement the functionality I need in jQuery and in qTip myself?

Comment: Did you manage to load the plugin in your widget without depending on the page's own jQuery? i am making a widget and encountered the same issue.

Comment: The only way I could find to do this is to create a variable that points to my jQuery and is visible from the global scope and change the code of the plugin to reference my jQuery. If the plugin is well written then you only need to change one place. Of course this means you need to host the changed version of the plugin yourself and keep it updated if it is important to you.